# Angular 4 - Encrypt data (AES) from angular and sent it

Tags: angular, typescript, aes

What do you think about the vulnerability in Angular 4 ? Because it's in the client.

I would like to encrypt a data with a key (Javascript AES) and send it to my API. After this, I will decrypt the data in my api.

Do you think it's a vulnerability?

Thank you

Comment: When you say "vulnerability" do you mean "security?" A vulnerability is a specific weakness that can be attacked. Do you mean a specific security flaw in Angular 4? It's unclear what you mean by "Do you think it's a vulnerability?" Do you mean "is this secure?" That completely depends on precisely what you're sending, who you're trying to protect it from, precisely how you're sending it, how you create and share the key, and many other factors. It's not possible to evaluate the system you've described.

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear, I wanted to know if it's secure. I use an authentification with google and it returns me an object with all the user's information. I would like to send this object to an API to store the user's information.

Comment: How do the client and server agree on an AES key? If it's hard-coded in the client, it's hard to see what benefit this is offering. What do you expect this to do that HTTPS isn't doing? While HTTPS has certain problems, do you believe you have the background to create something more secure than HTTPS?

Comment: Because HTTPS hides just the stream but not for the source or the recipient, right? So in my case, if you know my API and you know which object to send, you can send a wrong object, I don't want that. So my solution was to encrypt my object with a key ( example, key: "mypassword") and decrypt in my API with the same key.

Comment: So you're trying to hide information from the user of the API? Where are you going to put the key that the same attacker can't read it and create the same request? It's fine if you want to do that as a thin layer of obfuscation, but you won't stop anyone who has any idea what they're doing. Just make sure not to waste too much time on it (because it won't be very effective), and it's fine however you want to do it.

Comment: Yes but it's not I want to hide information from the user it's more I want to certify the object sending is from google. I want to put the key in my service in my angular application. I don't know if the attacker can read it

Comment: I think you want to rewrite your question with your specific case. What is the information you want to authenticate? (What does "the object sending from google" mean?) What attack are you trying to protect your system from?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to clarify. Using HTTP(S) already encrypts your data. Use an application such as WireShark to confirm this. Using HTTP (not HTTPS) is not advised as the payload can be read in the network as plain text.

If you still need further encryption (I would question why).

Secondly it depends where you are storing your data (I am assuming it is sensitive). If you are storing anything in the browser (Local Storage), then I strongly advise against this as it's not secure. The reason for this is because anyone could read such data using:

```
var yourSensitiveData = localStorage.getItem("your-data");
```

If you are saving data to Session Storage, then this is safe if implemented correctly because the data is only accessible between the client and server in which the session runs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I want to encrypt my data it's because I'm using an authentification with Google in my Angular application. Google returns an object with the user's information and I wish store this object in my database. However, I have to send this object in my API and this one is accessible every where ! So I would like to encrypt the object in angular, then send it in my API and decrypt with the key in my API. (I'm using HTTPS)

Comment: @Fasco I see. Do you mean "accessible every where" as in, anyone can perform a GET request on the data (in your database) using the API?

Comment: Say i have open session in browser. I can also try var yourSensitiveData =  sessionStorage.getItem("your-data"); and get the key right